# why nginx can not redirect request to port 80 on VPS?

Tags: nginx

I run 3 servers on VPS But nginx can not connect to server that run in port 80.
nginx can connect another port.
Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx cannot connect to the 80 port if this port is using by another application like Apache, NodeJs ... to further info can you show your nginx error log from systemctl ?

Comment: No other application will use this port 80. Further, the server that is on port 80 is available by the browser.

Comment: What is happening when nginx trying to redirect to 80 port any screen or log please?

Comment: nginx redirect this request to another port.Assumes that the server that port 80 is down.